# iPhone+Highlight Star when rated Accordingly

Tags: iphone, ios, ios4

i am developing an app where i want the user to rate any album,for example.After he rates the album i want the number of stars to be highlighted.Can anyone help me on this.i want to avoid using hardcoded images.

Answer (score 1):

You can start with [this tutorial](http://www.raywenderlich.com/1768/how-to-make-a-custom-uiview-a-5-star-rating-view).